# Workflow / Views: Specific state date

Tags: views, 6, workflows

I need a column (field) in a view where you can see the date of a specific state (Workflow state).

For example:
A content type news has three workflow states: new, reviewed, published. 
Now I need a view where you can see each news (also ones that haven't entered that state!) with a field where the date is shown when it was new, reviewed and published (sortable).
The Workflow module only provides "Previous time", but that's not specific to a state.

Any ideas?

I know how to program a views handler for custom table/fields but my problem is that the node -> workflow_node_history has an 1:n relation.

drupal 6, workflow 1.5, views 2.x

```
Example:

Title   | Date new     | Date Reviewed | published
---------------------------------------------------
Title1  | 01.03.2012   | 13.03.2012    | pending
Title2  | 02.05.2012   | 16.05.2012    | 20.05.2012
Title3  | 20.05.2012   | pending       | pending
```

Comment: They way I understand it, the data you are looking for simply does not exist? So it's really not related to Views at all, but how to coax workflow into storing more data?

Comment: The Data exist. Each (Workflow enabled) node has multiple workflow history entries (state and timestamp) in the workflow_node_history table... But with the default implementation of the worflow view plugins it is not possible to show a date of a specifig state....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Views PHP Module](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) provides a custome field that is click sort enabled

Value code example:

```
....
$result = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT stamp FROM {workflow_node_history} WHERE nid = %d AND sid = %d", $row->nid, $sid));
if(isset($result->stamp)) {
   return $result->stamp;
}
return 0;
```

Output code:

```
<?php 
print date('d.m.Y', $value);
?>
```

Enable click sort: sort numerically

Answer (score 0):

Add to the Filter criteria: *Where current state = reviewed*

Add the current field: *Workflow: current time*

That should return you the time of the state change to reviewed, for all nodes who are currently on the state "reviewed". If you want to show the nodes that haven't entered the state "reviewed", then just show all the nodes, and their current workflow state timestamp.

Disclaimer: I answered this on D7 so I don't know if that field and filter are available in D6.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But thats not the solution: 
"I need a view where you can see each news (also ones that haven't entered that state!) with a field where the date is shown when it was reviewed"

Comment: "If you want to show the nodes that haven't entered the state "reviewed", then just show all the nodes" - meaning, remove the current state filter. The workflow: current time will tell you the time the workflow state was changed to reviewed.

Comment: If ONLY you want to show the date for the reviewed state, then you can suppress the date for non-reviewed dates using Views hooks, preprocessors and templates.